# Ubuntu 12.10 VirtualBox Terminal

Tags: virtualbox, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I have recently installed Virtualbox 4.2.4 and I start a Ubuntu 12.10 image (*.vdi) under Virtualbox. It starts and works fine.

But weirdly I did not find any link to open a terminal(whichever terminal xterm, gnome, kde, i don't have any preference)

How can a terminal be opened once in the Ubuntu under VirtualBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically it's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or you can switch to another terminal with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (<kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>F4</kbd> etc.)

If you are running Ubuntu 12.10 then you can just click on a <kbd>Super_L</kbd> (<kbd>Winkey</kbd>) and type `terminal` it should show it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Which desktop you are using under Ubuntu?

Anyway, try ALT+F2 inside ubuntu and when a dialog box come out type "Terminal" Something should come up.